# Query to retrieve all row data for supplied column name

Tags: sql, eclipse, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using Eclipse and Oracle SQL Developer. My connections are all set up. I am trying to query my database in SQL Developer by passing in a column name as a variable.

For example, I just want to use something similar to this statement:

```
select * from CUSTOMERS;
```

but allow CUSTOMERS to be a variable where I can pass in any table name.

Currently this pulls all column names from given column name and connection:

```
final String query = "select column_name from all_tab_columns"
    +" where owner = ?"
    +" and table_name = ?";
try {
    headers = DAO.useJNDI(jndi)
        .setSQL(query)
        .input(1, host)
        .input(2, tableName)
        .list(String.class);
```

I want to do the same thing but with rows. Does anyone know how to do this? This is what I am thinking about so far:

```
final String sql = "select *"
    + " from table_name"
    + " where owner = ? and table_name = ?";    
 try {
    logger.debug(tableName+sourceJNDI);
    sourceList = DAO.useJNDI(sourceJNDI)
        .setSQL(sql)
        .input(1,  host)
        .input(2, tableName)
        .list(DatabaseCompareDto.class);
```

The main focus is the SQL statements. I know everything else works.

Comment: You want to pass the column name, or the table name? I don't really understand what problem you are having, or really quite what you re trying to do. Are you always querying a table that has owner and table_name columns?

Comment: Also not sure why you're talking about both SQL Developer and Eclipse - what is the connection?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your question correctly, I think what you want is to replace the first table_name in your SQL with ?, then add an additional .input( 1, tableName) :

```
 final String sql = "select *"
     + " from ?"
     + " where owner = ? and table_name = ?";    
 try {
     logger.debug(tableName+sourceJNDI);
     sourceList = DAO.useJNDI(sourceJNDI)
         .setSQL(sql)
         .input(1, tableName)
         .input(2, host)
         .input(3, tableName)
         .list(DatabaseCompareDto.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass the table name as a parameter. Instead of wasting your energy on such an alleged generic solution, use or create a small templating engine which allows you to replace the table name in your query before sending it to the database.